# Using $sceDelegateProvider to whitelist Youtube in Typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to allow users to enter Youtube URL's so I can display the videos on my site, but I need to whitelist Youtube first.  How can I fix my app.ts file to accommodate this in typescript?  The documentation looks something like this:

```
.config(function ($sceDelegateProvider) {
    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
        'self',                    // trust all resources from the same origin
        '*://www.youtube.com/**'   // trust all resources from `www.youtube.com`
    ]);
});
```

The problem is that my .config doesn't contain the function keyword, I believe because I'm using typescript.  My config currently looks like this:

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']).config(($routeProvider: ng.route.IRouteProvider, $locationProvider: ng.ILocationProvider, $sceDelegateProvider: ng.ISCEDelegateProvider ) => {
        $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
            'self',                    // trust all resources from the same origin
            '*://www.youtube.com/**'   // trust all resources from `www.youtube.com`
        ]);
```

I'm getting the same error that the url isn't being whitelisted.  Do I need to just paste the .config with the function in a different area, or is there a way to include the Delegate provider in the same place as my route provider and location provider, etc?

Comment: This looks like an error on Angular side to me. http://bit.ly/1mxkzDt this is how TypeScript transpiles to JavaScript, so it's not about `function` keyword.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like this isn't going to work, you end up getting other errors later.  Pretty easy to just use the embed URL, works just fine for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Tried making changes to the web config to allow this, but just not going to work.  Had to find another way to do this, using the embed url from the youtube video.